# Why isn't Finder updating a folder's contents?

Tags: finder, dropbox, refresh

Today I had the strange behavior that I added some files to a folder in Finder (that happens to be in dropbox) from Outlook, but Finder did not show them.  I could see them from the Open File dialog of Outlook and of Adobe Acrobat Pro XI, but returning to Finder, still not there.  Hitting the F5 key to force a refresh, still nothing.  Finally, I forced Finder to quit and relaunch, and they showed up.  This is OS X Yosemite v10.10.2.

What is going on?  Why would Finder not show the new files until forced to restart?

Comment: That happens to me on occasion, and if nothing else does it I restart the Finder (alt+cmd+esc), while I still do not know what is causing it in first place. on 10.9.5 MBA

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me. I'm on the latest version of Dropbox and OS X 10.10.5.

It is quite annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've known it happen if memory was being paged heavily, or if a drive was particularly full.

F5 has no effect on a Mac, btw, it's a Windows command.

The only real equivalent - to a system that really ought to never need to be refreshed under normal circumstances - is to switch view style…

…from list to column then back again, for instance…
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>  then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>